# drf-spectacular shows APIs registered with Django's APIView multiple times

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-spectacular

This is my APIView

```
  class NewUserView(APIView):
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
        renderer_classes = [CustomRenderer]
        serializer_class = NewUserSerializer
    
    
        @extend_schema(
            operation_id='Get user detail',
            responses={
                200: CustomRenderSerializer(serializer=NewUserSerializer)
            },
            tags=['User']
        )
        def get(self, request):
            users = request.user
            serializer = NewUserSerializer(users, many=False)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
        @swagger_auto_schema(operation_description="Update user info",
                             tags=['User'],
                             request_body=NewUserSerializer,
                             responses={
                                 200: CustomRenderSerializer(serializer=NewUserSerializer),
                                 400: ErrorMessageSerilizer
                             }
                             )
        @extend_schema(
            operation_id='Update user detail',
            responses={
                200: CustomRenderSerializer(serializer=NewUserSerializer)
            },
            tags=['User']
        )
        def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
            user = request.user
            serializer = NewUserSerializer(instance=user, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                emessage = serializer.errors
                return Response(emessage, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new-user/', views.NewUserView.as_view()),
    path('new-user/<str:pk>/', views.NewUserView.as_view())
    ]
```

With drf-spectacular is get these 4 endpoints in my documentation.[image]

I understand that it's due to 2 entries in the urls.py for the same APIView.

But my question is how do I implement it so that I get unique entries for each API in the documentation.

Note: I would not like to switch to viewsets. As there are many APIs implemented in this manner and I don't want to change code for each to the APIView.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the same view with two different endpoints.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new-user/', views.NewUserView.as_view()),
    path('new-user/<str:pk>/', views.NewUserView.as_view())
]
```

Try to change to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', views.NewUsersView.as_view()),
    path('users/<str:pk>/', views.NewUserView.as_view())
]
```

And define a **NewUsersView** for List and Create methods, and use **NewUserView** for Retrieve, Update and Destroy (for this you need a pk).